# How to make an SQL query when joined tables are one to many

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a table of candidates and a table of notes and there are multiple notes per candidate.

I'm trying to run an SQL query to get the details of a particular candidate by their ID (candID) and notes which match the candidate.

I'm not quite sure how to do this though since there will be many notes returned. Will I need to do two seperate queries?

Here's what I've got so far but it's incomplete (candID is the id for the candidate, candidateID is the related id field in the notes table):

```
try {
    $sql   = 'SELECT Firstname, Lastname, candID, Email, note
    FROM candidate RIGHT JOIN notes ON candID=candidateID WHERE candID='.$loadcandID.'';
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = 'Error fetching candidate: ' . $e->getMessage();
    include $errorpage;
    exit();
}
$row = $result->fetch();
    $cand = array(

        'firstname' => $row['Firstname'],
        'lastname' => $row['Lastname'],
        'email' => $row['Email'],

    );
```

Comment: A single JOIN query is sufficient to get what you want. Can you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? We can help you with the query.

Comment: I've never used SQL fiddle before, I might have to open another question on how to use that!

Comment: :) It's pretty self-explanatory and has good docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the JOIN properly you have to be specific in the query -

```
SELECT `candidate`.`Firstname` AS `first`, `candidate`.`Lastname` AS `last`, `candidate`.`candID` AS `id`, `candidate`.`Email` AS `email`,  `notes`.`note` AS `note`
FROM `candidate` 
LEFT JOIN `notes` 
ON `candidate`.`candID` = `notes`.`candidateID` 
WHERE `candID` = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks, so how would this be handled in the result when there are many notes but only one firstname, lastname etc.? I'm currently using $row = $result->fetch();

Comment: Use `$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` and make the changes I have added, the AS statements. For example you would then see first names in `$row['first']` `$row['note']` etc..